# JSfiddle "x" undefined" what's wrong with this code?

Tags: javascript

```
points = function() {
var p1 = this[0];
var p2 = this[1];
var a=p2.x-p1.x;
var b=p2.y-p1.y;
return Math.sqrt(a*a + b*b); 
}; 
points();
```

I am using "JavaScript the Definitive Guide" chapter 1. Whenever I put this code on JSfiddle it doesn't run and says:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined."

So `x` is not defined... how come in the book when they run it, it displays => 1.414 // the distance between the two points.

Practically none of the codes from the above mentioned book have valid codes that run without an error.

How do I adjust the code to make it run?

Edit: THANK you all for answering my question. I was copying word by word from the textbook. They didn't define the variables as well. Anyways thanks and more questions will be coming :P.

Comment: And also, x and y are undefined in the code you posted. It means you didn't say : var x = 'something';

Comment: @Praveen - take a look at the last line of code ;)

Comment: And @OP - it looks like you're missing a chunk of code from your example.  It looks like you start declaring a points 'class', and mid-way through you're writing a pythagorean function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this definition:

```
var points = function() {
    var p1 = this[0];
    var p2 = this[1];
    var a=p2.x-p1.x;
    var b=p2.y-p1.y;
    return Math.sqrt(a*a + b*b); 
};
```

The right way to call it is:

```
points.call([{x: 1, y:2}, {x: 2, y: 3}]);
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know the 'call' keyword. I just tried it and worked like a charm!

Comment: +1. But I dont get the reason  for a downvote?  Any wrong in using this approach?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the way you're calling the function, the context (`this`) will be `window` and as far as  I know `window[0]` and `window[1]` do not exist, I'm not sure what you're expecting but not once in your code have you defined any `Numbers` so what are you expecting to do mathematical operations on?

The way you would make it work would be to use the `arguments` object like so

```
p1 = {  
   x: 5, y: 2
};

p2 = {  
   x: 1, y: 8
};

points = function(p1, p2) {
    var a = p2.x - p1.x;
    var b = p2.y - p1.y;

    return Math.sqrt( a * a + b * b); 
}; 

console.log(points(p1,p2));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mbrz4/

Comment: How is this using the `arguments` object?

Comment: console.log() prints the result of points(p1,p2) to the console

Comment: @maček although i may have said that confusingly, it is still using the `arguments` object.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to do this

```
var distance = function(p1, p2) {
  return Math.sqrt(
    Math.pow(p2.x - p1.x, 2) + 
    Math.pow(p2.y - p1.y, 2)
  );
};

distance(
  {x: 1, y: 3},
  {x: 3, y: 9}
)

// 6.324555320336759
```

Also, don't forget to use the `var` keyword when defining variables.